# Python Replace text inside brackets with it's eval

Tags: python, regex

I have a file (or string if you want) like this:

```
$((2+1))
bbb$((2+0))a()
$((1+1))$((5**2))
$((variable+1))
```

And I want output to be like this (if variable = 1):

```
3
bbb2a()
225
2
```

Basically first I need to get text between $(( and )) I use this to do so:

```
re.search(rf"\$\(\((.*?)\)\)",template).group(1)
```

Than I need to replace all occurences with eval of what I got in previous step. How can I do it? Can I somehow compile the regular expression before and use it for both getting the text and replacing it? Thanks

Comment: Hello, you are supposed to provide a [mcve] so providing code you have work on and not asking about writing code for you, please read [ask] section and [edit] the question.

Comment: Those lines look like shell commands, are you sure you are using the right tool?

Comment: I would change your expression to `([^\$]*)\$\(\((.*?)\)\)` - that way, odd matches are the text between expressions and even matches are your expressions.  Then iterate over the list of matches, to build a new string, alternating between appending the odd matches and evaluating and appending the even ones...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need any library to use. All you need is using python built-in functions.

```
m = ["$((2+1))","$((2+0))","$((1+1))aa$((5**2))bb","$((0+0))"]

def OPGetter(string) :
    i = 0
    while i < len(string) :
        if string[i] == ")" :
            last = i
        i += 1
    res1 = (string[last+1:])
    #
    i = 0
    while i < len(string) :
        if string[i] == "(" :
            one = i+1
        i += 1
    i = 0
    while i < len(string) :
        if string[i] == ")" :
            two = i
            break
        i += 1
    return [string[one:two],res1]

result =[]
i = 0
while i < len(m) :
    string = m[i].split("$")
    if len(string) > 0 :
        res = string[0]
        string = string[1:]
    for item in string :
        code = "def returning() :\n    return "+ OPGetter(item)[0]
        exec(code)
        value = returning()
        res += str(value)+OPGetter(item)[1]
    result.append(res)
    i += 1
```

the result will have the final list of the answers.

Comment: That almost works, but if I have a line like this `$((2+1))a` It fails because it thinks that it needs to do eval from 2+1a, but I want it to eval only inside the $(())

Comment: Ok. I will fix that in a minute

Comment: You can see the code now.I edited my answer.sorry i took it so long.

Comment: I am so sorry that I need to bother you again. I need to preserve the surrounding string - it can be `aaa$((2+1))bbb` and output should be `aaa3bbb`. Sorry to bother you.

Comment: No problem at all. I'm here to help.I'll fix it again.

Comment: One question. If there is a line like this "aaa$((2+1))bbbaaa$((2+1))bbb" How the result should look like?

Comment: Like this: aa3bbbaaa3bbb

Comment: It is done.You can see the result in my answer now.I changed it.

Comment: I'm happy that I could help:))